# Flatten alongside with batch axis in TensorFlow / Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reshape, flatten

In a Sequential model, I'm trying to go from a layer output shape of `(None, 300)` to something like `(1,1,None*300)` to apply an `AveragePooling` layer. In fact I would like to flatten everything (even the batch axis), while both `Flatten` and `Reshape` layers always skip the batch axis. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Lambda` layer and the `K.reshape` from backend like this:

```py
from keras import backend as K

out = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (1, 1, -1)))(inp)
```